# How can I write a rspec test for change password function?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This function is used to change user's password with requiring user's old password. So how can I test this function with rspec.

```
def change_password
  @user = current_user
  if @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    @user.update_attributes({:password => params[:password]})
    head :no_content
  else
    render_error(:unprocessable_entity, "Wrong Password!")
  end  
end
```

Comment: Think about how would you verify that the password has been updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a rspec test for edit user information function and change password function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357256/how-to-write-a-rspec-test-for-edit-user-information-function-and-change-password)